# How configure webstorm to use import scss from different path in a project

Tags: sass, webstorm

I want to override several scss files of bootstrap. The paths in my project are like this

Source code of my scss:

```
/src/client/sass/style.scss
```

Source code of bootstrap:

```
/bower_components/bootstrap-scss
```

Now if i edit the style.scss in Webstorm it cant find the import

```
@import "bootstrap"
```

Im using gulp so i created a gulp task, that generates css from default bootstrap and my additions so i dont use the WebStorm watches.

How can i configure the project, so that the @import are correctly linked to bower components? Currently im using a symlink, but it feels like a hack.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just mark `/bower_components/`as **Resource Root** (`Mark directory as/Resource root`) - WebStorm will resolve imports relative to it

Comment: Now it jumps only to the bootstap directory

Comment: what is the exact name and path of the .scss file you import via '@import "bootstrap"'?